# could not load assembly System.Collections.Concurrent version 4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am new here in Xamarin so I installed the Visual Studio with Xamarin and when I created a new project and then run it without doing anything it gives me error like this

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1410,2): error : Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1410,2): error : File name: 'System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1410,2): error :    at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1410,2): error :    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1410,2): error :    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you install that package? It is available on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Concurrent/

Comment: @MarcGravell there are alot of packages with diff versions so can you suggest me specifically any one of them according to error ?

Comment: The current one. The one st the top. The one you would get by default.

Comment: Thnx @MarcGravell

Answer (score -2):

I run this command "Install-Package System.Collections.Concurrent" in package manager console.Then go to add reference and then click on browse then go to C: -> windows->microsoft.net->Framework64->v4.0.30319 folder->select the system.colection.concurrent.dll->click OK.